# Sublime Text Editor Regex (Find & Replace - Add Prefix and Postfix)

Tags: regex, .htaccess, sublimetext3

I'm facing an issue where I have a list of website addresses like following:

```
http://xsi82.com
http://xsi122.com/view/8383.html
http://sdf242.com/view/4483.html
http://oudi38.com/view/182483.html
https://83jsla.com/forum/view1234.html
https://hello192.com/page/hello.html
http://hsl1092.in/world
```

There are like 2000+ URLs.

I want to basically extract out the domains and put them on a ban list in .htaccess

I want to remove everything that is after `.com` and I want to remove everything that is in the prefix like `http://` or `https://` or `http://www.` or 'https://www.' and sometimes some websites are like `www23.` or any other sub-domain.

Once that is done and I get a clean list, I need to add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(.+.)?
```

in the prefix of the line and

`/ [NC,OR]`

at the end.

The end result of would look something like:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(.+.)?xsi82\.com/ [NC,OR]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: `^http(s)?://(www\.)?||(?<=(.com)).*$`

I used this but it is limited to .com only.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this `((\w+\.\w+)(?=\/))|((?<=\.)|(?<=\/\/))((\w+\.\w+)\n)`

In this way, you do not need to **delete** before and after the domain
you just need to **extract** the **domain** from the heart of **url**

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/NTuWre/5)

---

If you want to delete everything except the domain:

1. remove everything before domain: `(.+(?|(?>\/\/.\.)|(?>\/\/)|(?>(ww.)\.)))`[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pC0Hdy/1/)
2. remove everything after domain: `(?<=\w)(\/.+)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pC0Hdy/2)

Comment: This is awesome to select the domains. But I want to delete everything that is NOT the domain.